# SQL - Exclude items from a table with a specific content

Tags: sql, special-characters, sccm

I'm running a query which works just fine when I'm working with normal chars but not with russian, polish etc chars.
For instance, when I'm excluding a few items from the selection, this works:

```
and ARPDisplayName0 NOT LIKE '%Microsoft Office ScreenTip%
```

These lines instead are not being processed since I see them in the report:

```
and ARPDisplayName0 NOT LIKE '%Narzędzia sprawdzające pakietu Microsoft Office%'
and ARPDisplayName0 NOT LIKE '%Средства проверки правописания Microsoft Office%'
```

How can fix it?
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: did you try put the N before a string :
 
and ARPDisplayName0 NOT LIKE N'%Средства проверки правописания Microsoft Office%'

Comment: I did not, since I'm a total beginner and indeed that worked. Post it as an answer :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's Unicode, so you need to put a N prefix before the strings, N stands for national character :

```
DECLARE @x NVARCHAR(max)
SET @x= N'unicode'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't use proper character set for you DB. Check your db encoding is UTF-8.

```
SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

Then try again.

Comment: That's Microsoft's. The answer's been given by hoangnnm. Thanks for your help.